# configure and watch log4net using blob store

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-blob-storage, log4net-configuration

we are using log4net with custom appenders to log our stuff from azure machines to table store, and that works fine. What we need now is to use blob-store to configure logging for  all our instances in one place and be able to modify it on run-time, just modify the config file in blob store and few moments later all my machines should know about this change.

Simply said what I need is:

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure(Uri blobStoreUri, bool watch=true)
```

or even better:

```
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(string blobStoreUrl, TimeSpan refreshInterval)
```

I googled arround but was not able to find anything like that. What would be the best way to implement this or do you know any similar implementations of this?

thanks
almir

Comment: If you just need to change the logging level at runtime I suggest to use the solution proposed by Imtiaz and then check the trace threshold level. Eventually you should consider to use a trace appender for log4net and use the built in azure diagnostic trace functionalities that can automatically export trace data to a table storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is solution we implemented than

https://gist.github.com/kaza/9207832

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to configure log4net to look for a file stored in the blob, but the windows azure diagnostics provides a way to specify the configuration information in a log file that's stored in blob.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh411551.aspx